# Which fields of AI are actively researching consciousness?

Tags: reference-request, research, artificial-consciousness, ai-field

[Max Tegmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Tegmark) discusses the topic of consciousness in his book [Life 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_3.0) and comes to the conclusion, that consciousness is substrate independent. If his analysis is correct, it should be possible to create artificial consciousness. [The integrated information theory (IIT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_information_theory), while currently only just a theory, also points in this direction.

This leads me to the question: which fields of AI research, if any, are currently actively engaged in this domain?

So far, I've only found research concerning consciousness in neuroscience and discussions of experts in philosophy.

Are there any projects publicly known concerning artificial consciousness or organizations that are active in this regard?

Comment: Yes, the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project is related to your question. Pitrat's book *Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine* is explaining in details a possible approach, and is about an experimental software.

Answer (score 4):

I think we still have a long way to go before any progress is made on artificial consciousness. However, researchers are taking inspiration from traits of human consciousness. One relevant paper is [Machine Theory of Mind](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07740) by DeepMind. They show that their model can (at least to some extent) represent the desires, beliefs, and intentions of agents that it observes. It even passes a form of the [Sally-Anne test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sally%E2%80%93Anne_test), showing that it can represent the *false beliefs* of an agent.